# Op-amp missing GND rail protection (for failsafe applications)

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I have designed a Howland current source using a [TLV9351](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tlv9351). From the power rails of the op-amp, the GND pin is externally connected to the connector. When the GND pin is removed, the IC starts to heat up and breaks down.

The troublesome part of the job is that when the GND pin is removed, the op-amp internally moves the V- pin to the V+ pin. How can I prevent this situation? How can I set up a system that will disable the op-amp and prevent it from burning when GND is removed?

An important consideration is how the output will behave if we lose ground connection "physically". In terms of safety, we also need to evaluate this possibility (failsafe design). Our case is the floating GND state.

[image][image]

Comment: If you remove GND from V-, but *not* from the load. You allow basically all circuit voltages to be below the specced Input Voltage Range in absolute Maximum ratings -> Recipe for desaster.

Comment: Hi! This situation is not always desired, if the gnd cable breaks, it is for protection.

Comment: Simply tie Load directly to the V- pin at the circuit. If the GND connection breaks (or is broken), it must do so for all intents and purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You should shut off the resistor load current path to ground. You could do this either by switching it upstream of the relay, or by an P-MOSFET connected to the power supply.

Comment: It's the negative supply, so a PMOSFET would need a below-GND gate voltage to run. Do you mean NMOSFET ?

Comment: @tobalt nope , infineon ,onsemi, TI has smart mosfets for the gnd loss protection,we have to upply high side PMosfet to power pin of opamp

Comment: You could do either, if you block the current pathway.

Comment: @tobalt if the switch is open in the ground goes positive and the V- rail floats to the positive rail